# Change figurename inside \ContinuedFloat

Tags: floats, formatting, naming

I want to change the name inside a `\ContinuedFloat`. Example:

```
\begin{figure}[]
    \centering%
    % ...
    \caption{Somecaption} %
\end{figure} %
\begin{figure}[]\ContinuedFloat
    %%%%%
    \let\oldfigurename\figurename%
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Cont.~\oldfigurename}%
    %%%%%
    \centering%
    % ...
    \caption{Somecaption} %
\end{figure} %
```

However, this does not work. I think `\ContinuedFloat` might manipulate `\figurename` or the `figure` environment entirely so as not to use `\figurename`. How can I still change the figurename? (I have checked that my `documentclass` does indeed use `\figurename`.)

Comment: I get “Cont. Figure 1” in the second `figure` environment. Please, make a full compilable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think that re-defining `\figurename` locally is a bad idea since this macro is used for multiple purposes. If used for a different figure, but inside the environment where the re-definition took place, it will also print "Cont. Figure X", even if Figure X isn't a continued one.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you only want the caption labeled differently I would just change the caption labeling, nothing else. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig} % offers \ContinuedFloat

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{Cont}{Cont.~#1~#2}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=Cont}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    % ...
    \caption{Somecaption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    % ...
    \caption{Somecaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```